# RadGrid - filter textboxs, any way to control their width dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with a filtercontrol on it.  The grid fits the size of the window, but certain views have quite a few columns and when the columns get shrunk down, the filter controls don't resize to fit.  Is there any way to set those filter controls to auto fix within the width of the column?

[image: filter]

Comment: How was this done? Would be nice to see the code to dynamically resize so that filter button is in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at column editors. I think they'll let you control the style of controls nested in the grid from outside of the grid.

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn ColumnEditorID="TextBoxColumnEditor" ... />

<telerik:GridTextBoxColumnEditor ID="TextBoxColumnEditor" runat="server">
    <TextBoxStyle Width="500" />
</telerik:GridTextBoxColumnEditor>
```

Here's a link that explains it in detail:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdstylingthroughdeclarativecustomeditors.html

Comment: there is a built in way to control the width (FilterControlWidth), but that sets it to a static pixel width.  I was hoping there was some way to set it to auto based on the column width

Comment: What about setting the width to 100%? Wouldn't that make it cover the width of the column??

Comment: But if you set FilterControlWidth=100% then the text INPUT takes up 100% of the column width and there's no room for the filter button. How did you work around this?

Comment: I posted an alternate answer below that attempts to address the obvious issues with setting a percentage width.  Please check it out and provide feedback if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In latest RadGrid, there is an easy fix for this. Just set the filter control width in your markup or code-behind as shown below.

**Set Filter Control width in markup**

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductName" FilterControlWidth="80%"
 HeaderText="Product Name" UniqueName="ProductName" HeaderStyle-Width="130px"
 AllowFiltering="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

**Set Filter Control Width in code-behind**

```
boundColumn.FilterControlWidth = Unit.Percentage(80);
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the screenshot, the filter textbox width is beyond the header column. To set it within limit you can use the following JQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function fn() { $(".riTextBox").css("width", "80%"); });
```

In this 'riTextBox' is css class of filter textbox generated by RadGrid. You can set the width as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked, the size of the filter button was 20.16px, so you can use put this in your css:

```
.RadGrid .rgFilterBox {
        width: calc(100% - 20.16px);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and didn't find the 80% width solution sufficient.  As your column gets wider, the gap between the filter button and the text box grows and it isn't a very clean solution.  I have a mostly working solution for the problem that uses jQuery to create appropriate wrappers around the elements.  It currently doesn't work well for situation where you are using a column that would filter for a date range (uses two date filters in the Telerik controls), but other than that has served me well.

```
function fixRadGridFilterBar() {
jQuery('.rgFilterRow > td').each(function () {
    var cell = jQuery(this);
    var isDate = false;
    if (cell.children().length) {
        var filterBox = cell.find('.riTextBox');
        if (filterBox.length) {
            if (cell.find('.RadPicker').length){
                filterBox = cell.find('.RadPicker');
                filterBox.css("width", "100%");
                isDate = true;
            }
        }
        if (!filterBox.length) {
            filterBox = cell.find('.rgFilterBox');
        }
        if (filterBox.length) {
            var filterWidth = cell.find('.rgFilter').outerWidth();
            var padRight = isDate ? 0 : parseInt(cell.css('padding-right'));
            var marginRight = parseInt(cell.css('margin-right'));
            var filterPadding = (isNumber(padRight) ? padRight : 0) + (isNumber(marginRight) ? marginRight : 0);
            cell.css('position', 'relative');
            cell.children().wrap("<div class='filter-input'></div>");
            filterBox.parent().css('float', 'left').css('width', '100%');
            filterBox.wrap('<div></div>');
            filterBox.parent().css('padding-right', (filterWidth + filterPadding).toString() + 'px');
            cell.find('.rgFilter').parent().css('width', filterWidth.toString() + 'px').css('position', 'absolute').css('right', '0');
            cell.children().wrapAll("<div style='position:relative;'></div>");
        }
    }
});
jQuery('.RadGrid > table').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).wrap('<div class="rgHeaderWrapper"></div>');
});
```

}